# How to rotate a Three.js Vector3 around an axis?

Tags: javascript, vector, rotation, three.js

How to rotate a Three.js [Vector3](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Vector3) by a certain angle around an axis?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
var vector = new THREE.Vector3( 1, 0, 0 );

var axis = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 1, 0 );
var angle = Math.PI / 2;

vector.applyAxisAngle( axis, angle );
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.doob. You forgot a 3 after THREE.Vector.

Comment: You should now use Vector3#applyMatrix4(matrix) instead of Matrix4#multiplyVector3(vector)

Comment: You should now use `vector.applyAxisAngle( axis, angle )`; three.js r.69

Comment: @WestLangley - why is the result {x: 2.220446049250313e-16, y: 0, z: -1} are there rounding errors we should be aware of?

Comment: See it in action here: 
https://codepen.io/arpo/pen/LkXYGQ/?editors=0010

Comment: Verified this rounding error: Windows 10, Chrome 63, Intel i7-6700K:
before: 1 0 0
after:    2.220446049250313e-16 1 0

Comment: How can we apply the same transformation to geometries? applyAxisAngle seems to only work with meshes

Comment: this is still the correct answer as of r.121