# Inclined rotation between an object in Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, three.js, orbital-mechanics

I'm trying to reproduce a solar system like in Three.js, but I don't manage to make planet rotate in an inclined way around the star :

[image: Rotating angle]

Here is a fiddle sample but with the wrong rotation :
http://goo.gl/MzcwI

I tried this solution : 
[How to rotate a 3D object on axis three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060734/how-to-rotate-a-3d-object-on-axis-three-js) without success.

If someone have a clue to help me,
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had to add an element at the root position of the pivot, it creates a sort of new plan that you can rotate.

Solution [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tknew/VsWb9/566/).

```
jsfiddle
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
function animate() {

  pivot.rotation.y += 0.01;
  pivot.rotation.x += 0.01;
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  render();

}
```

Comment: Nop it does a strange movement at the end of the rotation I linked the solution on the next post

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rotate just using the position vectors of the mesh you can simply do something like

```
theta = 0;/* Global variable */
function render(){ 

    orbiter = /* Get the planet you want to rotate*/;

    orbiter.mesh.position.x = Math.cos( theta ) *100;
    orbiter.mesh.position.z =  Math.sin( theta ) *25;
    orbiter.mesh.position.y  =  Math.cos( theta ) * -60;
    theta +=.02; 

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}

function animate(){ animation_id = requestAnimationFrame( animate ); render(); }
animate();
```

Your going to have to play around with the values to get the desired rotation angles - especially for the position.y value.  Increasing theta should increase the speed.