# three.js - fix rotation axis of tube geometry

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, three.js

I've a tube geometry built with 2000 points stored as JSON data.
The tube has band (curves) also. I am using `TrackBallControls`.

Now when I rotate the tube, it is rotated in all three dimensions.
The rotation is not limited to any particular axis.

I am using following code after creating `tubeMesh`.

```
// to make rotation only on x-axis
var v = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0).normalize();           
var matrix = new THREE.Matrix4();
tubeMesh.applyMatrix(matrix.makeRotationAxis(v, 0));            
tubeMesh.applyMatrix(matrix.makeTranslation(0,-1500,0));

if ( tube.debug ) tubeMesh.add( tube.debug );
scene.add(tubeMesh);
```

This code does not work as the tube is rotating on all three dimensions.
Even I've tried the functions defined in below question.

[three.js rotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060734/how-to-rotate-a-3d-object-on-axis-three-js)

**How do fix the rotation axis so that the tube will be rotated only on specified axis ?**

using r53

Comment: Trackball controls rotates the camera, not the object. I would suggest that you abandon trackball controls, and refer to the three.js examples for how to use the mouse to rotate an object on a single axis.

Comment: I am using trackball controls for panning and zooming facility as I've to render this model on iPad. Which example should I refer ?-@WestLangley