# Rotate a cube over a surface using three.js with specific feature

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to make an animation involving cube on a flat surface. I can turn it on the x/y axis only (no need to see underneath it). I can then tip over the cube over any edge – if a side of my cube “touches” the surface, it sticks to it (surface gets colored there) and vanishes from my cube.

Here is the depiction of what I am trying to say:

[image]

When you turn it over one more time in the same direction.

[image]

How can I do this?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could have a state machine, and you render one thing or another depending on the current state?

Comment: What is a state machine? Does that come under three.js? Sorry I am new to Three.js and webGL.

Comment: Google will give you much more detailed information that what I could :)
Good for you that still have to learn the path. And good for you to have projects like this to do so. Enjoy.

Comment: @RicardPérezdelCampo. Thank you so much. I will do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your question, I took it as a coding-challenge and spent some hours to implement something like this. Here is the result: http://codepen.io/usefulthink/pen/zoLLpP – I cleaned up the code and added a lot of comments, so you might find a lot of useful stuff in there (also, feel free to use the code in any way you like)

So essentially, a few things to note upfront:

- as noted by @Carlos [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41012525/rotate-a-cube-over-a-surface-using-three-js-with-specific-feature/41063881#41063881), I constructed the cube and wireframe from independent meshes and used `THREE.Group` to keep them together.
- three.js has two very great methods, `THREE.SceneUtils.attach` and `THREE.SceneUtils.detach` that are incredibly helpful for this kind of stuff (didn't know about them before)

The basic procedure I implemented is this:

- before starting the animation, check if there is a face at the bottom that 
  could be detached from the box. Detaching is done with

  ```
  THREE.SceneUtils.detach(bottomFace, bottomFace.parent, scene);
  ```

  which removes the object from it's parent (in our case the group with the moving parts of the cube) and adds it back to the scene at the very same position.
  At this point, the animation to switch the material is also triggered.
- for the animation, we need to have an pivot-point, so the cube can be rotated over it's edges. This can be realized using a special groups and the attach/detach-methods I mentioned earlier. Have a look at the

  ```
  function setPivotPosition(position) {}
  ```

  to see how you use any arbitrary point as the pivot-point for rotation 
  of an object.
- using a separate group as the pivot-point has one major advantage: We can update the animation using the `pivot.rotation` property provided by three.js. This also allows us to use a tweening library like tween.js to handle all the animation.

If you have any more questions about this, please let me know :)

Comment: this solution is so elegant. Thank you so much. Especially for the comments in the code.

Comment: how can I restrict the boundary for the cube movement. I figured that cube is not stopping when moved even if I reduce the size of the mesh (surface). If I hold any key little longer cube is disappearing.

Comment: in that case I would probably just check the current-position in the beginning of the move-routine (via `var nextPos = new THREE.Vector3().setFromMatrixPosition(box.matrixWorld).add(direction)`) against a bounding-box (see `THREE.Math.Box`)  using `box.containsPoint(nextPos)` to see if the next-position is still allowed. If not, just return and do nothing (in my example you'd need to return `Promise.resolve()` to make it work). I will update my example accordingly.

Comment: I really really thank you for your help. It means a lot to me. I hope it wont be too much to ask ; but I got one more doubt which is : after all the faces of the cube are stuck on the surface, if they are attached it looks like a net. So how can I make this net lift by 90 degree up and see whether it can turn into a cube. Something like this: http://www.mathematikus.de/10/

Comment: (RE http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41012525/rotate-a-cube-over-a-surface-using-three-js-with-specific-feature/41082897?noredirect=1#comment69600115_41082897) I can't see anything under that link, tried in various browsers but nothing shows up in the content-area. Anyway. It sounds like you want the very same process just in the opposite direction, so the very same would apply here, use a new function `attachFace` to transfer a face on the ground into a group and rotate the group using `setPivotPosition`.

Comment: thank you so much for the suggestion. I tried to work it out. Here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/irshad001/pen/qqvMaN 
The problems I faced : 1) Initially putting all the faces on the surface ( I tried changing the parameters of Createboxface function but turns out they are normals to the axes. If I make all the faces normals as (0,-1,0) then all 6 faces are overlapping. 
2) In this scenario I don't need to make the faces forming a cube one by one , it should happen at once by clicking a button one time. 
I just need to see whether given joint faces form a cube.

Comment: can you please tell me which parameters should I amend so that I can make all the cube faces as bottom faces? but not overlapping. Sorry for asking too may questions.

Comment: Hi @Artiga, I'm not quite sure what you want to achieve exactly, so it's a bit difficult for me to answer that. You mean like laying them out initially as if they were unwrapped? I would like to write a few points about this, why don't you just open a new question, that'd be easier than having a comment-thread here?

Comment: I have opened a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320005/folding-rectangles-to-form-a-cube-using-three-js

I hope I have I succeeded to explain it this time properly.

Answer (score 1):

What about using square surfaces instead of a cube. Use six square surfaces and animate the assembly. Change the rotation axis in each step.

Here there some samples of rotations.

[How to rotate a 3D object on axis three.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060734/how-to-rotate-a-3d-object-on-axis-three-js)