# Folding rectangles to form a cube using three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to make a cube with given 6 faces lying on the surface as a cube net with one face movable. Something like this:

[image]

In the above picture, there are 6 faces, one face ( blue one) is movable.

One can rotate them up together along their edges to form a “net”.
Once they think they are finished, they can press a “fold it” button – all edges turn up 90 degrees to create the cube (or may not be a cube if he hasn't joined the  blue face at proper position.)

Below is intermediate status after pressing "fold it" button.

[image]

After the faces are folded it should like this:

[image]

The corresponding animation is given here:  http://www.mathematikus.de/10/

(somehow that link is not working on mac)

I am not sure how to go about this. Any help is  appreciated.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: 8? a cube has 6 faces... :-)

Answer (score 11):

You can use hierarchy of objects.

```
var obj1 = new THREE.Mesh(...);
var obj2 = new THREE.Mesh(...);
obj1.add(obj2);
```

There's a good [example](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=hier#webgl_geometry_hierarchy2) of it.

So, using this principle, I made animation for folding the cube, given in your question. Of course, this is not the ultimate solution, this is just a starting point.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/w35mjrwf/) example

upd: I've updated the fiddle. You can start folding by clicking the `PressMe` button. Animation made with Tween.js (see the `foldTheCube()` function)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. How can I make that only blue side movable/dragable  and once the cube is formed it should not animate any more.

Comment: Mark the answer as accepted,please, if it fits your needs ) About moving/dragging objects, there's a good example of [draggable cubes](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_interactive_draggablecubes.html)

Comment: Yes I definitely will. :) . I I tried putting the DragControls.js library and adding its events on side5, but it dint work.

Comment: ehm.. mark my answer, not my comment ;) I never worked with DragContorls.js, so I can't say anything about it.

Comment: hehe :) @prisoner849, I will mark your answer once I get it to work. I am also trying how can I drag colored face and put anywhere adjacent to white faces and make the cube (if possible)

Comment: as I have given you the bounty points, now can you please tell me how can I move/drag that blue face? :)

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/za29828m/) example of using DragContorls. Uncomment the line `//sides.push(s);` and you'll be able to drag all the planes there.

Comment: Thank you so much @prisoner849, This is great but this isn't folding  to form a cube when click a button . Something like this : http://www.mathematikus.de/10/

Comment: jsfiddle now broken - here's an updated one https://jsfiddle.net/fd5e48ka/1/

Answer (score 0):

The jsfiddle is now broken - here's my attempt at an updated jsfiddle

I removed Tween to simplify it

https://jsfiddle.net/fd5e48ka/1/

```
function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    var angle = Math.PI / 2 / 300;
    sides[0].rotation.y += angle;
    sides[1].rotation.x += -angle;
    sides[2].rotation.y += -angle;
    sides[3].rotation.x += -angle;
    sides[4].rotation.x += angle;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```