# Robotic arm's movements with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

i'm trying to realize a robotic arm using the three.js library. My idea is to use hierachical levels in order to create the arm's geometry in such a way that the first level of the geometry would be the basis of the movements for the entire arm. Could someone help me accomplishing this task?

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320005/folding-rectangles-to-form-a-cube-using-three-js   the fiddle in the answer has planes to make up the sides of the cube, but the concept is the same: https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/w35mjrwf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a different Mesh for each part in the robotic arm,
and then add each part to it's parent Mesh.
then when you will rotate a parent Mesh, It's children Meshes will rotate with him.

for example:

```
var mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();

var mainHandGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(50,10,10);
var mainMesh = new THREE.Mesh(mainHandGeometry ,mat );

var midHandGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30,5,5);
var midMesh = new THREE.Mesh(midHandGeometry ,mat );

var lastHandGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(15,3,3);
var lastMesh = new THREE.Mesh(lastHandGeometry ,mat );

midMesh.add(lastMesh);
lastMesh.position.set(10,10,10);
mainMesh.add(lastMesh);
midMesh.position.set(10,10,10);
```

Now when you will rotate mainMesh it will rotate with it's children.
If you will rotate midMesh it will rotate with lastMesh.