# Rotate a segment (not an object)

Tags: three.js

I'm using three.js to create an origami effect image transition (ie texturing an object with the current image, folding the segments in the object, perhaps with a color wash, downloading the next image and then unfolding the object to reveal the new one.) I want to write an engine that can produce different shapes depending on the album.

The design so far is to define the segments based on where the folds have to be, shift the Z index of the segment to be folded and then rotate the segment (and any attached segments) 180 degrees in the direction of the shift.

The trouble is that there seem to be functions for rotating objects but not, so far as I can see, segments. Short of re-calculating the segments by hand, is there any way to rotate segments of an object?

Comment: @WestLangley You've removed all references to WebGL? I'm prepared, if necessary, to go down to the WebGL level if three.js doesn't have utilities to run it. Hell, I may end up going into WebAssembly and using OpenGL directly.

Comment: As the author of the question, you can revert the edits if you feel it benefits your question. There are _many_ questions tagged both `three.js` _and_ `webgl` that don't necessitate the second tag. That said, I think you should make it more clear in your question about what you are trying to modify. My answer makes an assumption that you're modifying vertex positions, which _can_ be done at lower levels, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with doing what you want to do the way you want to do it (if I understood correctly) is that you're constantly updating the geometry buffer, which, in turn, needs constantly re-sent to the GPU. This may have good enough performance for small meshes, but it's still a generally expensive operation.

A different way to approach it is to consider how your "folding" will take place, and design groups of objects around that. For example, to fold a square diagonally, you'll need two triangles. If each triangle is a mesh, then you can apply specific rotations to each one to mimic being folded along the common edge. So, for whatever folding effect you want to produce, simply create groups of meshes and define *how* they un/fold.

The difference between two frames can be imperceptible. The unfolded images would all be mapped the same, perhaps to a plane. Then, within a single frame, you swap the frame for the fold-able collection of meshes, and begin you animation. The image can map to the collection the same as the single plane through the use of UV coordinates, which tie key points on the image to the vertices of the folding segments.

If this helps, great. If you have questions, or would like an example, let me know, though I don't have time to put together a complex demo right now.

Comment: Thanks, Jim. I don't expect you to put a demo together, that's on me to figure out, but I've obviously got to re-think my approach. This is my first attempt at WebGL so I'll post the results when I get them for suggestions and future reference.

Comment: @Mike Just for some ideas, there's the answer that coinsides with the thoughts from TheJim01's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41320905/4045502

Comment: Thanks, prisoner, the mesh is what I was missing!