# How calculate rotational increment in THREE.js

Tags: three.js

For drag function, I'm making objectB follow objectA like:

```
var positionDeltas = objectA.position.clone();
postitionDeltas.sub(objectAOldPosition);
var newPositon = objectB.position.clone();
objectB.position = newPosition.add(positionDeltas);
```

Can angle increments be done similarly? Can I subtract/add quaternions in a similar way?:

```
var rotationDeltas = objectA.quaternion.clone();
rotationDeltas.sub(objectAOldRotation);
var newRotation = objectB.quaternion.clone();
objectB.quaternion = newRotation.add(rotationDeltas);
```

Clarification: this is what I *want* to do; however, I do know that eulers can't be subtracted, and subtraction isn't defined for quaternions. So....how would one who knows what they're doing approach this three.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 const q = new THREE.Quaternion();

 q.multiply( q2, q1.inverse() );
```

Quaternion `q` represents the rotation from quaternion `q1` to `q2`. You can then apply this rotation to your 3D object via `.applyQuaternion()`.

`three.js R91`

Comment: How to get axis of rotation corresponding to q? I would like to use the code in answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060734/how-to-rotate-a-3d-object-on-axis-three-js/18296348 but I need to find axis and angle somehow

Comment: Your solution works, thank you. But I dont have R91, so how can q be applied to a 3D object manually, i.e. without .applyQuaternion?...thank you

Comment: Yes. It is `object.quaternion.premultiply( q );`.