# World position of mesh is not updated after rotation

Tags: three.js

I have three cube meshes (A, B, C) each within a group. Then I parented the groups into a hierarchy.

Group A -> Group B -> Group C

I need to rotate group B around a world axis and the find the position of mesh C.

For rotation around a world axis I used the code given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11060734/how-to-rotate-a-3d-object-on-axis-three-js?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have a small `rotate_cubes` function to perform the rotation. After rotation it logs the result of `getWorldPosition()`. But I do not get the updated position. I get the old position of the cube C.

```js
function rotate_cubes(group) {
 group.rotateAroundWorldAxis(make_vector3(), make_vector3(1, 0, 0), 15 * THREE.Math.DEG2RAD)

  let pos = make_vector3()
  cube3.getWorldPosition(pos)
  console.log(pos)
}
```

How can I calculate its position after rotation?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you please try to update the world matrix of Group B via `updateMatrixWorld()` after applying the rotation? In the next step, try to retrieve the world position of mesh C.

Comment: Thank you very much @Mugen87! It works now. I made the incorrect assumption that the matrix gets updated automatically.

Comment: Also please add this as an answer so I can mark it as the answer. Will be easier for others to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to update the world matrix of Group B via [Object3D.updateMatrixWorld()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.updateMatrixWorld) after applying the rotation. In the next step, try to retrieve the world position of mesh C.

`three.js R105`