# Anvantage of self invoking function inside function definition

Tags: javascript, function, three.js

whats the advantage of a function definition like this: `obj = { func: function(){return function func(){return this.something;};}() }`

Story:
I was looking for a way how to rotate a Three.js Vector3 by a certain angle around an axis and found this: 
[How to rotate a Three.js Vector3 around an axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747510/how-to-rotate-a-three-js-vector3-around-an-axis#comment21869562_10747728)
I was interested in how the function works and looked it up: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/math/Vector3.js. The function looks like this:

```
applyAxisAngle: function () {

    var quaternion;

    return function applyAxisAngle( axis, angle ) {

        if ( quaternion === undefined ) quaternion = new Quaternion();

        return this.applyQuaternion( quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( axis, angle ) );

    };

}(),
```

So whats the reason for this way of the defining a function?

Comment: Considering position of `d` and `n`, `anvantage` is some typo

Comment: advantage is to hide `quaternion`. `applyAxisAngle` can use it, but no one else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediately-invoked function expression (IIFE) lets the author of that code give the `applyAxisAngle` function a truly private `quaternion` variable that nothing else anywhere can see.

That code basically does this:

```
var quaternion;

// ...

applyAxisAngle: function applyAxisAngle( axis, angle ) {

    if ( quaternion === undefined ) quaternion = new Quaternion();

    return this.applyQuaternion( quaternion.setFromAxisAngle( axis, angle ) );
},
```

...but keeping `quaternion` entirely private, rather than sharing it with code in the scope where all of this appears.

It defers constructing the `Quaternion` object until the first time it's called, and then it reuses that object in all subsequent calls by using the value from that private `quaternion` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the reason `applyAxisAngle()` was written that way was not to keep `quaternion` private, although that is, in fact, a side effect of the implementation.

It was written that way to avoid instantiating a `new Quaternion()` every time the method is called, and consequently, avoiding garbage collection.

`applyAxisAngle()` is often called in tight loops -- many times a second. Writing the method this way, the `Quaternion` is instantiated only once.

The implemented construct is called a "closure".